# How to use Shared-preferences to implement  change password functionality in my Android application?

Tags: android

all
i want to create one activity window in which user can change his password.
Like:

```
   Old Password=
   New Password=
   Retype Password=
```

Now when the user tries to login for my application the password must be the new one...
so,please give some sample of it. how to achieve it.

Thanks in Advance--

Comment: The same logic applies. Perhaps what you need to do is to get your hands dirty.

Comment: You haven't said what the difficulty you are having is...  you must already have the user's current password, so check the "old" password against it, then check if the two new passwords match, if so overwrite the old password with the new.  What is the problem you have encountered with this?

Comment: @dave your right....but as i am new to this technology i want to know how it can be achieve in android i.e which functions or classes to use for the same....thanks in advance...

Comment: you would use the same "functions and classes" that you used to implement your current login functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this.

One way is that you can pop-up a dialog, which contains three `EditText` for old password, new password and repeat new password.

Some tips:

1. Set `android:password="true"` to asterisk the input password
2. You can check the old password on the lose focus of the `EditText`

Comment: @johny rght but user setting password n old password,so we can match it??old password must store some where or what??

Comment: @smith store a hash of the password if you must, not the actual password somewhere (in the app or on the server) and then compare the hash of the entered password with the stored hash. If you want to improve the security of this hash scheme, generate a random seed for THIS user and store the seed. Then seed the password, and then recursively hash the seeded password where iterations > 1000. Then store this hash with the original random seed.